# Configurable checkouts based on store view

Tags: magento-enterprise, checkout, multistore, ee-1.13

I'm working on Magento site with multiple stores. All stores use the same theme but now I need to use a different checkout for one of the stores. It would be something like having a three step checkout module for one store view and one step checkout for the others.

Can anyone advise on the best route to take in order to achieve this or offer any advice that seems relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I added a feature flag which consists of a value stored in core_config_data. All checkout request go to the same controller and before a page is rendered the value of the core_config_data record is checked and the user is directed accordingly